# Synat error - The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

Tags: java, syntax

I am getting a syntax error on checking strings with `data[i]`

```
String data; // has value
ArrayList<Byte> byteArr = txfCheck.getFilterByteArray();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    for (Byte b : byteArr) {
        if (b.toString().equals(data[i])) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I be checking it?

Comment: please format your code and complete it

Comment: Please provide some code and tell us how you tried to solve it.

Comment: If data is a String then data[i] is going to be syntactically incorrect

Answer (score 6):

Well yes - `data` is a `String`, and you can't use an indexing expression like `data[i]` on a string.

Perhaps you want:

```
if (b.toString().equals(data.substring(i, i + 1))
```

Although it's far from clear that that's a good idea. `Byte.toString` probably doesn't do what you expect it to. Perhaps you actually want:

```
if ((char) b == data.charAt(i))
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#chatAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) to treat the String as a `char[]` and retrieve a `char` at index `i`.

Then for `equals()` to work, either compare them as Strings

```
if (b.toString().equals(data.charAt(i)+"")
```

Or, compare them as characters

```
if ((char) b == data.charAt(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use,

```
b.toString().equals(data.charAt(i));
```